# Template Toolkit include hook?

Tags: perl, hook, template-toolkit

Is there some type of a hook that will be executed when I include a template and in which I can change the path to the template?

e.g.

```
[% INCLUDE test %]
```

And I want to change the path to 'test' to be something like 'AE/test.tt' or 'FR/test.tt'.

---

The idea is to change the path to the template without changing the template in which the include is situated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way of doing this would be to use the `INCLUDE_PATH` parameter when constructing your `Template` object:

```
my $tt = Template->new({INCLUDE_PATH => 'AE'});
```

Building a new `Template` instance isn't any big deal, so there's no strong reason not to make a new one on the fly whenever you're about to process a template, but, if you're in a persistent environment and really need the performance, there's always the option of creating more than one:

```
my %tt;
$tt{ae} = Template->new({INCLUDE_PATH => 'AE'});
$tt{fr} = Template->new({INCLUDE_PATH => 'FR'});
# ... code ... code ... code ...
$lang = 'ae';
# ... code ... code ... code ...
$tt{$lang}->process($template_name);
```

Comment: 10x this may work because I can pass a sub to the INCLUDE_PATH (I am using Dancer and I use the build-in template engine handling). And as far as I found out there isn't any type of hook, that could allow me to change the template name, or any type of build-in alias functionality (e.g. a place where to pass a hash and the INCLUDE to use the passed template name as a key and the value to be the real path to the template), am I right?

Comment: I'm not aware of any hooks or aliasing functionality, no.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is possible like this `Template` example :

```
[% mytest = 'AE/test.tt' %]
[% INCLUDE  $mytest  %]           # 'AE/test.tt'
```

Not tested here.

See http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_INCLUDE

Comment: The idea is to dynamically change the path to the template